# Manually reset session timeout (keep alive) in a spring web application

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-mvc, tomcat

Is it possible to manually reset the timeout interval of a specific session for a user that is currently logged in my web app?

I would like the ability to do something similar to this :

```
  public void keepAliveForUser(long userID) {

      Session session = this.userSessionManager.getUserSessionById(userID);
      session.resetTimeOut();

  }
```

P.S - keep in mind this function is not being called in a follow up to a user request. (i.e. It's called from a cron job, a scheduled task, etc...)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HttpSession#setMaxInactiveInterval` to change the session expiry time on the fly

Java Doc

> Specifies the time, in seconds, between client requests before the
>   servlet container will invalidate this session. A negative time
>   indicates the session should never timeout.

Usage

```
//session will expire after 2 hours of inactivity
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(2 * 60 * 60);
```

Answer (score 0):

Session timeout hierarchy:

1. `$tomcat_home/conf/web.xml`
2. `$your_webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml`
3. manual invocation of `HttpSession.setMaxInactiveInterval(int)`